# *some* placemarks not showing up in simple KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth-plugin

Here's a link as an example:

http://goo.gl/maps/s76T

Very straight forward KML, with some placemarks (#10-21) simply not
showing up on the map. I'm not very familiar with KML, but I've been
reading, debugging and searching for this problem and can't figure this out. 
The icon links seem fine, and placemarks #10-21 show up if I erase most of the other ones
(say take out 22-44).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find this validator helpful but annoying: [KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm). It does seem to have a problem with your `<description>` tag not being next to `<name>`.

As far as i know, you're supposed to reference a style, not include it in the point definition. See: [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style)

Google earth is not a good place to build these; not only do many things display differently, in my experience it will also break your tags.

As far as specifically answering your question: not much of an idea why that'd happen. Try re-naming or assigning IDs to your points, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is much more strict about applying KML schema rules than Google Earth. Here's where the KML schema lives: http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd. The namespace identifies your KML as version 2.0, which never had an official spec. The current official version is KML 2.2. The 2.2 namespace is "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2".

In general, if you restructure your KML Placemarks, it should work. Geometries (your Point elements) should be the last thing in your Placemark element. For the elements you're using, the order should be:

name
description
Style
Point

Also, there's no `creator` attribute, instead you should use an `atom:author` element just under your Document tag:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#atomauthor

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think I changed what you commented on, but i Still get the same behaviour. I'm unclear why only #s 10 to 21 don't work if there's a consistent problem with the elements?

http://goo.gl/maps/oUVG

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with KML rendering on Google Maps. There is an internal bug filed, but no timeline on a resolution yet.

Comment: Hi, please, post a link with this bug. Thanks.

Comment: Huh, well there probably wasn't a public link. But the bug was almost certainly fixed. ... but its irrelivent now anyway, as Google Maps can no longer render KML **AT ALL**. KML rendering was never implemented in the new version came out a few years ago.